# Opportunity analysis or Opportunities analysis?

Tags: grammatical-number, possessives, attributive-nouns

Please help me to say it correctly in other words in English: 
**The Anasysis of opportunities.** 
(it's from the SWOT analysis).

  Considered options are:
    1) Opportunities analysis
    2) Opportunities' analysis
    3) Opportunity analysis

I've seen that 3rd option is commonly used, but is it correct for using as plural form?

How is it to distinguish plural form from singular if it is written: *Opportunity analysis* ? From the context of following text? Or using singular form we should always use the indefinite article *an*, for example: 
*An opportunity analysis*?

Comment: Hi, ok, thx. But I don't know how to transfer the question between portals. And I've found some resources with different options, for example: 
 (opportunities) https://www.smartdraw.com/strategic-analysis/examples/opportunities-analysis/   ;    and here simple (opportunity anasysis) https://e145.stanford.edu/term_project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Opportunity Analysis** is correct.

You wouldn’t see a “ ‘ “ in front of opportunity/opportunities

And Opportunities are for more than one opportunity (plural). This sounds like Opportunity Analysis. If you’re talking about multiple, it’d Opportunities Analysis.

Comment: Thank You! Very helpful!